# Modeling communication costs in MPI

Tags: mpi

Does anyone know of any papers that discuss communication costs in MPI programs? I am trying to predict the time taken by (say) the communication step in two phase I/O. That would depend on the no. of processes, the size and number of messages sent/received, network interconnect and architecture, etc. It would be helpful for us to come up with a formula to assess the time taken by communication alone. I have read some papers , but none of them handle the case where multiple processes are communicating at the same time.

Comment: Can you describe tha case you interested in in more detail? What is the operation is between "multiple processes are communicating at the same time." (who will send data to whom)

Comment: Assume you have 10 processes in which 2 are aggregators (processes dedicated to performing I/O), the first step of the I/O requires all processes to send their data to the aggregators (lets say procs 0..3 send data to process 8, and processes 4..7 send data to process 9). This is a simple scenario. What happens when you change the total no. of processes, no. of aggregators, message sizes, etc. ? How can you model the time required to perform this communication step?

Answer (score 0):

The most critical elements in any time estimate will be the total data to be sent, and the speed of the interconnect.  That should give you an effective "minimum" time for the message transfers.

After that, you can measure the actual time taken and use that to determine a rough efficiency rating for the MPI implementation.  As the amount of data scales up, the time required will also scale up using the scale factor.  This is a *very* rough way to get an estimate.  Keep in mind that as the data size crosses certain interesting thresholds (e.g. page size, cache size, and so on) the scale factor will likely need to be revised.